# Hide filled in model from Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I would like to create a serializer with Laravel. Currently, I have my model (`CountryEntity`), with a function to `getSingleCountry()` to hide a specific field (`is_active`).

**Model**

```
class CountryEntity extends Model
{
    public $table = "countries";

    protected $fillable = ['id', 'name', 'code', 'language', 'is_active'];

    public $timestamps = false;

    public function getSingleCountry()
    {
        $this->makeHidden['is_active'];

        return $this;
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```php
public function show($id)
{
    $country = $this->country_repository->getById($id);

    $country = $country->getSingleCountry();

    return Response::json(['type' => 'success', 'message' => 'Get country', 
        'data' => $country, 'status' => 200], 200);
}
```

But the field "is_active" is always visible...

Comment: Why don't you just use `protected $hidden = ['is_active'];` in your `CountryEntity` model? That's what it does; hides fields when it is converted to `JSON`. Also, this seems like the wrong syntax: `$this->makeHidden['is_active'];`, wouldn't it be `$this->makeHidden(['is_active']);` (calling a method, you need to use `()`)

Comment: Thank you @TimLewis ! Fixed ! I would like to have many "serializer" in my model, sometimes "is_active" will be hidden, sometimes no : that's why I didn't push 'is_active' in $hidden.

Comment: No problem! And yeah, that makes sense. Also, please don't add the solution in the question. Add a new answer below with how you fixed it, and eventually you can accept that and properly close this question. Otherwise, this might get closed as a "typo" question (since you just missed the `()` on your method call)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here was missing `()` on a method call. This line:

```
$this->makeHidden['is_active'];
```

Isn't explicitly doing anything. It's a little surprising this didn't raise an `Undefined index` error, but regardless.

When trying to call a method of a Class, you need to use `()`:

```
$this->makeHidden(['is_active']);
```

The `makeHidden()` method accepts an array of parameters to temporarily set into `protected $hidden` on the Model, which hides them when the Model is converted to `JSON`, and other serialization.